# sucessive redirections using javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm trying to load sucessive urls using javascript from firefox developer console.

So far, I've tried with different versions of this code:

```
function redirect() {

    var urls = ["http://www.marca.com", "http://www.yahoo.es"]
    for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(location.assign(urls[i], 5000));
    }
}
```

But the result of this code is that it only redirects to the last url from the array. Every page should be fully loaded before iterating to the next page.

I've also tried using window.onload, but with no luck either. It's always the last url which is loaded.

I guess this must be something very basic (I'm new to javascript), but can't find any solution to this.

Any help or hints of what I'm doing wrong here would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're issuing 2 redirects with ~1ms in between, so of course you'll end up on the last page. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Thank's for the hint, but it does the same, no matter how long do you set the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the console after running your code, it appears that a request is sent to the first URL but is soon aborted when the loop runs for the second time and instead it redirects to the latest URL.

My suggestion would be to open the pages in different tabs, if that works for you.

You can do,

```
for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) { 
window.open(urls[i],"_blank");
}
```

This will open the pages in the new tabs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your solution works, but I need it to happen in the same tab. I've tried the code in a test web page to see wether the issue was related to the use of firefox console, but I get the same behaviour...

Comment: Can you please explain why you need to do the redirections in the same tab?

Comment: I intend to load a list of numbers into the page form. The list of numbers is quite big (like 150 or more) so I can't load so many tabs. The numbers are passed through the url. Seen the difficulties I'm thinking now about a different approach and load the numbers directly in the form, and clicking the button to submit programmaticaly.